# sonar plugin : how to get sonar's metric

Tags: plugins, sonarqube, metric

I'm working on a Sonar project and I have to make a plugin in order to get metrics and to compute them.

In order to understand how it works, I'd like to try to do the following examples:

- Get the value (complexity) and to compute it as a double or a float value.
- Take the complexity value (MetricsCore.COMPLEXITY) and if it's more than 200, write a message to say that it's too complex.
- Take the number of comments lines and multiply it by 10.

I know that in these examples what I want to do is useless, but it's just to understand how to get the Metrics Core value and take their value, and to create new Metrics.
I don't find a lot of documentation....

Thank you very much

For information, I will use Sonar-reference-plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find our sample plugins here: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/plugins. "sonar-reference-plugin" should give you lots of information.

This should help you to better understand how things work.

Comment: Yes, I work with this example, but on this project, they have to display the RANDOM value but it doesn't work...
So I really don't know how to do it.
And moreover they doesn't use the metric as a value in order to compute it or to modify it.

Comment: Ok :)
I want to get the value of complexity (complexity), compare it with a reference value(ref_complex) that I'll choose, and if complexity > ref_complex, I want to display a warning message :)
Thank you :)

Comment: And the problem is when I want to compare the complexity value with a number, it never works :(

Comment: To get the metric: context.getMeasure(...).getValue()

Comment: To create a violation: context.saveViolation(...)

Comment: Thank you very much 
I'll try with those functions

Comment: I have tried this method to get the number of code lines:             Measure test_value = context.getMeasure(CoreMetrics.NCLOC);
     if (test_value != null) {
  context.saveMeasure(CodeQualityMetrics.TEST, test_value.getValue());
  }
   else {
  double value2 = 8000;
  context.saveMeasure(CodeQualityMetrics.TEST, value2);
  }                                                        but everytime i show on Sonar 8000 :( I don't understand why....

Comment: Please come on sonar DEV mailing list to discuss this. This will be easier than here.